# Custom component containing filterFunction problem when using multiple instances

Tags: apache-flex, components, arraycollection, filterfunction

I have a main app that is using two instances of a custom MXML DropDownList component.

I included all the logic and queries within the custom component to query MySQL and fill an ArrayCollection with the result.

In my first DropDownList, I want to show all the available currencies avilable in my database.

In the second DropDownList, I only want to show the CAD and USD currencies using a filterFunction.

I don't know why, but once the filterFunction is applied to the first element, the second act like they are sharing the same currenciesList variable (THIS IS MY PROBLEM).

***[Bindable]*** for *currenciesList* is required to bind to my aSyncListView.

***public*** for *currenciesList* is required in order to be used in the main app.

And no matter if my variable is public or private, I have the same bug... Please view the output at the end of this message.

---

**The call in my main app look like :**

```
<mx:Form>
  <formElems:DropDownListCurrencies id="product_cost_price_curr"
    currencyCadUsdOnly="true"/>
  <formElems:DropDownListCurrencies id="product_price_curr"/>
</mx:Form>
```

**Now my custom component :**

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import classes.SharedFunctions;

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

        [Bindable]
        public var currenciesList:ArrayCollection;

        public var currencyCadUsdOnly:Boolean = false;

        protected function dropdownlist1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            getAllCurrenciesResult.token = currenciesService.getAllCurrencies();

            // DEBUG just to show the id of the component
            trace('id:' + this.id + ' (getAllCurrencies)');
        }

        protected function getAllCurrenciesResult_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            currenciesList = getAllCurrenciesResult.lastResult;

            // DEBUG before filterFunction
            trace('id:' + this.id + ', currencyCadUsdOnly:' + currencyCadUsdOnly + ', currenciesList.length:' + currenciesList.length + ' (BEFORE filterFunction)');

            if (currencyCadUsdOnly == true) {
                currenciesList.filterFunction = filterCadUsdOnly;
                currenciesList.refresh();
            }

            // DEBUG after filterFunction
            trace('id:' + this.id + ', currencyCadUsdOnly:' + currencyCadUsdOnly + ', currenciesList.length:' + currenciesList.length + ' (AFTER filterFunction)');
        }

        protected function filterCadUsdOnly(obj:Object):Boolean
        {
            return (obj.code == 'CAD' || obj.code == 'USD');
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <s:CallResponder id="getAllCurrenciesResult" result="getAllCurrenciesResult_resultHandler(event)"/>
    <currenciesservice:CurrenciesService id="currenciesService" fault="SharedFunctions.showError(event.fault.faultString, event.fault.faultDetail)" showBusyCursor="true"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:AsyncListView list="{currenciesList}"/>
```

Finally let's have a look at the console output. **I'm expecting the ArrayList to have a length of 7 on creation of the second component... :**

```
id:product_prices_curr (getAllCurrencies)
id:product_cost_price_curr (getAllCurrencies)
id:product_prices_curr, currencyCadUsdOnly:true, currenciesList.length:7 (BEFORE filterFunction)
id:product_prices_curr, currencyCadUsdOnly:true, currenciesList.length:2 (AFTER filterFunction)
id:product_cost_price_curr, currencyCadUsdOnly:false, currenciesList.length:2 (BEFORE filterFunction)
id:product_cost_price_curr, currencyCadUsdOnly:false, currenciesList.length:2 (AFTER filterFunction)
```

**THANKS FOR THE HELP!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need to have the same list in multiple places with differing filters, what you need is a ListCollectionView. That way you can apply a filter to *it* and you won't affect the original list. It's as easy as:

```
var secondList:ListCollectionView = new ListCollectionView(originalList);
```

And your `secondList` can have any filter you like without affecting the original list, with the added benefit of updating when items are added or removed from the `originalList`.

See here: [mx.collections.ListCollectionView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html)

Comment: a big thanks for that. I makes thing so much simplier to declare that private ListViewCollection in my component. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code to be the following:

```
        if (currencyCadUsdOnly == true) {
            currenciesList = new ArrayCollection(currenciesList.source);
            currenciesList.filterFunction = filterCadUsdOnly;
            currenciesList.refresh();
        }
```

Hope this helps!